# How to get all the methods of an object ? [Javascript]

Tags: javascript

```
const str = new String('john');    

console.log(str instanceof String); // true
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(str)) // [ '0', '1', '2', '3', 'length' ]
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String))  // [ 'length', 'name', 'prototype', 'fromCharCode', 'fromCodePoint', 'raw' ]
```

Although str is an instance of String, why does it not have the properties of a String ? And why aren't `toLowerCase`, `toString`, etc not shown in `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(str)`

Comment: Because those aren't that object's own properties.

Comment: `toString()` isn't `String`'s own property ? Please explain

Comment: Those belong to `String.prototype`

Comment: `String` is a function/constructor. You really want to look at `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype)`

Comment: @Aditya own properties are the properties assigned to the object, but with the dot notation you can't access just them, but also the prototype inherited properties. You should study how javascript works in order to understand this

Comment: Btw try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype)`

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the prototype object with [`Reflect.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/getPrototypeOf) and list all own properties.

```js
const str = new String('john');    

console.log(str instanceof String);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(str));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Reflect.getPrototypeOf(str)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because prototype of object is not available on the instances of object, but there is another `__proto__` which is.

PS. a good article describing this concepts https://hackernoon.com/understand-nodejs-javascript-object-inheritance-proto-prototype-class-9bd951700b29

Comment: Use of `__proto__ `is not recommended: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate an object (native or custom), you automatically inherit all its methods.
  Also all methods of native objects are in `__proto__`: because it is better to put the methods in the prototypes to save space in memory.

From my personal experience in Javascript,inherit a method does not mean that it belongs to you.